# UIActivityViewController saves 2 PDF copies to files app

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to simply save a PDF file to the "Files" app on an iOS device.

When the user hits the "Save to Files", then "Save" action, I get 2 copies of the PDF saved onto the device.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong??

Below is my code

```
@objc func downloadPdfTapped() {
        if let fileURL = createTempPdfFile() {
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [.assignToContact, .markupAsPDF]
            present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print("\n\nERROR CREATING PDF\n\n")
        }
    }


    private func createTempPdfFile() -> URL? {
        let tempFile             = "temp_statement.pdf"
        guard let tempFolder     = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return nil }
        self.tempFileURL         = tempFolder.appendingPathComponent(tempFile)
        guard let currentFileURL = self.tempFileURL else { return nil }

        do {
            try pdfData.write(to: currentFileURL)
            return currentFileURL
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured this out!

I was writing my temp file in:

`guard let tempFolder     = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return nil }`

However, I really should have been writing it in the temp folder, so something like this worked...

`let tempFolder = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory`

That gets me the *real* temporary directory.

Then, when you are done, don't forget to delete your temporary files!